# How to find all answers that a certain person has answered me?

Tags: support, search, statistics, data-explorer

I feel that there are persons that actively help me by giving quality answers to many of my questions for a long time.

One week ago, I got the feeling that a person who answer a certain question of mine, is one of them.

Just curiosity, are there any way to get the list of all questions that OP answer my question?

Comment: Likely not directly, but through use of [the data explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @Makoto It is quite complex.   It might be too much (for me) to learn stackoverflow's query just for this.   But, thank!  :)

Comment: Does Stack Overflow need more of one-to-one features like Facebook 'See friendship'?

Comment: @ManojKumar I think they are purposely less social than sites like FB because this is not what SO is about. That would probably only increase the cliques, quid pro quo (serial voting), and other undesirable behaviors.

Comment: Well, curiosity is the mother of knowledge and you got an exceptional answer below, but I wish to remember that SO is about good answers not about people.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The following [SEDE Query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/607566?UserId=3577745) does that:

```sql
;with answers as 
(select a.id 
     , a.owneruserid 
from posts q 
inner join posts a on q.id = a.parentid
where q.owneruserid = ##userid:int?3577745##
)

select a.id as [Post Link]
     , a.owneruserid as [User Link]
     , (select count(*) 
        from answers ans 
        where a.owneruserid = ans.owneruserid) as [# tot answers]
from answers a
order by 3 desc , 2
```

When run today you'll get this result:

[image: result of answers]

Keep in mind that SEDE is only updated weekly, on Sunday.